# how to get phase difference between two given functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, physics, graphing-functions

My physics teacher gave a function $y = A\sin(\omega t \pm kx)$ and he gave it a phase shift of $\pi$ and said that the function would become $A\sin(kx \pm \omega t)$.
I wanted to verify it myself so I plotted graphs on desmos. I had it in my mind that phase shift meant how much the graph will shift horizontally with respect to first graph.
But upon graphing $y = \sin(x)$ and $y = -\sin(x)$, I realized that the 2nd graph has a shift of $2\pi$ with respect to the first one.

I am measuring this length shown in this image:

[image: Graph of two sinusoids.]

Am i missing something? is the above mentioned definition of phase shift wrong? (please educate me about the right one) am i measuring the wrong length? or whether my concepts are little loose.

Your help will be appreciated!! :)

Comment: Both your red and green graphs are not of sin and -sin, rather they each have period 4pi.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(\theta \pm \pi) = -\sin \theta$.

Comment: are you sure your plots aren't $\cos$ and $-\cos$ because $\sin(0)=0$

Comment: @wjmccann I assume that both plots are shifted by $\tau/2$ in opposite directions.

Comment: The better thing to do in Desmos is to plot equation (1) and then equation (1) with a phase shift of $\tau/2$, and see that they're each other's additive inverse:  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fwyvtqaoc3

Comment: i am sorry for my inconsistency the graphs are y=2sin(0.5x+pi/2) and y=2sin(0.5x+pi/2+pi)or y=-2sin(0.5x+pi/2) . please help me out on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your $\sin$ curves are stretched. Check [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/amplitude-period-frequency-phase-shift.html) resource for some nice pictures and term descriptions, but using the curves you have
$$
y_1 = 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\pi\right)\right)
$$
so the phase shift here is $\pi$, not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as we need to remove the stretch term first before we can see the shift. For your other curve
$$
y_2 = 2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) = 2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(x+3\pi\right)\right)
$$
which is a phase shift of $3\pi$. As such the shift between the two is
$$
3\pi-\pi=2\pi
$$
which is what you found on the graph